# Can you use wildcards in search scope rules?

Tags: search, search-scope

I have a list on the root web of every site collection that I would like to create a scope for.  I tried the following rule and got 0 results:

folder = http:// servername /*/Lists/Listname

If I substitute the asterisk for the site collection name, I get results.  I just don't want to have to add a scope rule for every site collection that is created.

1. folder = http:// servername / sitecoll1 /Lists/Listname
2. folder = http:// servername / sitecoll2 /Lists/Listname
3. folder = http:// servername / sitecoll3 /Lists/Listname

Is it possible to create a rule using wildcards that will satisfy my need?

Comment: Assuming the list stores same type of content, you can create a Search Scope based on Content Type instead of URL

Comment: You're right, I like that solution better.

Comment: ok, I promoted that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list stores same type of content, you can create a Search Scope based on Content Type instead of URL

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question in the title of the post, but it is a valid and more elegant solution to my underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about 2010, but 2007 supported only prefix matching.

You are probably better served with a custom search web part that could query your WebApp, pull all the site collections and feed them into the query.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584220(v=office.12).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551453.aspx